# AttributeError: 'HttpResponseSeeOther' object has no attribute 'url'

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to test for a ***303 See Other*** status code when a User attempts to login. Django does not have a built in class to handle this status code, so I constructed a sub class of *HttpResponse*.

```
from http import HTTPStatus

from django.http import HttpResponse

class HttpResponseSeeOther(HttpResponse):
    '''Represents a 303 status code'''
    status_code = HTTPStatus.SEE_OTHER
```

Next, I constructed a TestCase to test a View's response when it is passed valid form data. However, the test raises this error: `AttributeError: 'HttpResponseSeeOther' object has no attribute 'url'` . Going over the Django docs, I cannot see any reference to a Response object having an URL attribute.

How can I go about addressing this error so that a server returns a `200 OK` response after a successful `303 See Other` redirect?

**test_views.py**

```
class TestUserLoginPage(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        User.objects.create_user(username="User", password="password")
        cls.login_creds = {
            'username': 'User',
            'password': 'password'
        }

    def test_successful_login_redirect(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("login"),
            data=self.login_creds,
            follow=True
        )
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("photos:main_gallery"), status_code=303)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "photos/main_gallery.html")
```

**views.py**

```
class LoginPage(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = UserAuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, 'login.html', context={'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        form = UserAuthenticationForm(request, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, f"Welcome {request.user}!")
            return HttpResponseSeeOther(reverse("photos:main_gallery"))
        messages.info(request, "Login Failed. Username not registered.")
        form = UserAuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, "login.html", context={'form': form})
```

```
ERROR: test_successful_login_redirect (photo_app.tests.test_views.TestUserLoginPage)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\photo_project\django_photo_app\photo_app\tests\test_views.py", line 34, in test_successful_login_redirect
    follow=True
  File "C:\photo_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 545, in post
    response = self._handle_redirects(response, data=data, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "C:\photo_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 686, in _handle_redirects
    response_url = response.url
AttributeError: 'HttpResponseSeeOther' object has no attribute 'url'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Subclassing from `HttpResponse`, you should subclass your custom response from `HttpResponseRedirectBase`:

```
from http import HTTPStatus

from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirectBase

class HttpResponseSeeOther(HttpResponseRedirectBase):
    '''Represents a 303 status code'''
    status_code = HTTPStatus.SEE_OTHER
```

Here is a reference for implementation from [Django's github source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L494).